# Django Rest Framework how to display related models as one json file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a few different models with a fact table of scenarios and 6 dimension tables that relate to it below as examples:

```
class fScenario(models.Model):

     #Variables
     scenarioId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.scenarioId)

     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('scenario-detail', args=[str(self.scenarioId)])

    class Meta:
         ordering = ['scenarioId']



class dADA(models.Model):

     #Variables
     scenarioId = models.ForeignKey(fScenario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     dateTimeId = models.DateTimeField('ADA Time/Date')
     latitutde = models.FloatField(default=0)
     longitude = models.FloatField(default=0)
     instanceType = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='ADA')

     def __str__(self):
         return f'{self.scenarioId}, {self.instanceType}'

     class Meta:
         ordering = ['dateTimeId']
```

serializers.py

```
class fScenarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = fScenario
        fields = ['scenarioId', 'description']

class dADASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    scenarioId = fScenarioSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = dADA
        fields = ['scenarioId', 'dateTimeId', 'latitutde', 'longitude', 'instanceType']
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'fScenario', views.fScenarioViewSet)
router.register(r'dADA', views.dADAViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
```

views.py

```
class fScenarioViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = fScenario.objects.all()
     serializer_class = fScenarioSerializer

class dADAViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = dADA.objects.all()
    serializer_class = dADASerializer
```

I'm using rest framework view sets and I currently can see in my API separate fScenario and dADA views but cant figure out how to link the dADA to the fScenario view on one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) and Django [many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) backward relation to retrieve related objects:

serializers.py

```
class fScenarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dADA_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = fScenario
        fields = ['scenarioId', 'description', 'dADA_list']

    def get_dADA_list(self, obj):
        return obj.dada_set.all().values()
```